# Placeholder in Django for login AuthenticationForm doesn't show up

Tags: html, django, forms, web, placeholder

I'm creating a login form in Django using AuthenticationForm. I want to add placeholders for username and password fields. The placeholder attribute doesn't work. That doesn't make sense since I have a similar signup form, where everything shows up correctly.

**my forms.py**:

```
class UserSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'nickname'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'e-mail'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True,
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password again'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        exclude = []


class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'nickname'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = AuthenticationForm
        AuthenticationFormFields = ('username', 'password')
        exclude = []
```

Answer (score 1):

You have been using `forms.widgets.TextInput`, that is not correct.

Look at the [widgets documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/). Basically it would look like:

```
widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'nickname'})
```

instead of

```
widget=forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'nickname'})
```

You can also declare a widgets attribute containing a `<field name>` => `<widget instance>` mapping directly on the `Meta` of your `ModelForm` sub-class.